# Visual Studio 2010 Extension - events not called

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I trying to hook several Visual Studio events. Unfortunately I am failing in the first step. The event handlers are never called.

So my question is what I am doing wrong?

Here a little excerpt of my code.

```
// here are some attributes
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
public sealed class VSPackage : Package {
  EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte_;
  EnvDTE.DocumentEvents documentEvents_;
  EnvDTE.WindowEvents windowEvents_;

  public VSPackage2Package() {
    Trace.WriteLine("I am get called.");
  }

  protected override void Initialize() {
    Trace.WriteLine("I am get called too.");

    dte_ = (EnvDTE80.DTE2) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
      GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");

    windowEvents_ = dte_.Events.WindowEvents;
    documentEvents_ = dte_.Events.DocumentEvents;

    windowEvents_.WindowCreated +=
      new EnvDTE._dispWindowEvents_WindowCreatedEventHandler(
        windowEvents_WindowCreated);

    documentEvents_.DocumentOpened +=
      new EnvDTE._dispDocumentEvents_DocumentOpenedEventHandler(
        documentEvents__DocumentOpened);

   Trace.WriteLine("Everything fine until here.");
  }

  void documentEvents__DocumentOpened(EnvDTE.Document document) {
    Trace.WriteLine("Never called");
  }

  void windowEvents_WindowCreated(EnvDTE.Window window) {
    Trace.WriteLine("Never called");
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

I get it working, looking at other sample code, I figured out that they sometimes getting the DTE object differently. Changing

```
    dte_ = (EnvDTE80.DTE2) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
      GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
```

to

```
    dte_ = GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
```

and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

I'm pretty sure that if you do the same from an Addin it would work. Packages can be painfull sometimes.

In fact, when a package is loaded the shell (DTE) may not be fully loaded yet. Try to register your events when it is.

<strike>To do so, use the OnShellPropertyChange event and the Zombie state to know when to register.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3097a0e1-68e3-47ea-a4ba-8511571b2487/</strike>

Read the following, I think it answers your question. Note : [The GetService method is the same as calling GetGlobalService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/17/three-new-managed-package-framework-features-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

> **1. ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider**
>
> This new static property on the
>   ServiceProvider class allows access to
>   the global service provider from any
>   code, as long as it is called from the
>   main UI thread. This property is
>   closely related to the
>   Package.GetGlobalService static method
>   which was available in previous
>   versions of the MPF. The problem with
>   Package.GetGlobalService was that it
>   would fail if a package had not yet
>   been initialized. This led to subtle
>   ordering bugs in code that used the
>   MPF libraries without initializing a
>   package of their own. Sometimes they
>   would work only because another
>   package had already initialized the
>   global ServiceProvider on their
>   behalf. If that other package was
>   uninstalled, or perhaps moved to a
>   different version of the MPF, that
>   static would no longer be initialized
>   causing Package.GetGlobalService to
>   fail.
>
> Now, in MPF 10, you can call
>   ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider at any
>   time as long as you are calling from
>   the UI thread. For compatibility, this
>   mechanism will still use the
>   ServiceProvider created by the first
>   Package to be sited but, in the case
>   where no Package has yet been
>   initialized, MPF 10.0 now has the
>   ability to obtain the global provider
>   from the registered COM message
>   filter. Package.GetGlobalService() is
>   also hooked up to this new mechanism.

Comment: doesn't help, OnShellPropertyChange is called, but never with the property mentioned there, moving my event registration there anyway succeeds in execution, but also the events are not called

Comment: If you never get the property it means that the DTE is already loaded. So this is not the problem.

Can you please try with an addin to make sure your implementation is ok?

Maybe the events are not fired when you think they should.

Comment: I edited my question, getting the DTE object diffenrently was the try. Allthough i don't know why ... explanations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not boxing and unboxing your DTE object. I found this was the issue for me.

See my solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/eb1e8fd1-32ad-498c-98e9-25ee3da71004